# skewed results due to omitting intersecting populations

Tags: sampling, ab-test

A randomizer assigns visitors to my website to one of two groups, for an A/B test, e.g. at 25% and 75% probabilities for A and B respectively. It's supposed to assign them consistently, so that if someone returns to the site later he'll be in the same group again. Unfortunately, it's buggy, and a small percentage of visitors get reassigned to the other group. The more someone returns to the site, the more likely he'll be reassigned to the other group.

In analyzing the test's results, I've been omitting anyone affected by the bug, i.e. looking at the "clean" cohorts of people who're in only one group. But now I realize a problem with that:

"A" people are more likely to also be "B" than "B" people are likely to be "A". (After all, people who're both "A" and "B" are, say, 5% of the entire population, but that's about 5/25 of the "A" group but 5/75 of the "B" group.) Thus, more of the more-engaged users (who return more) are likely to be omitted from the "A" group in my analysis than from the "B". That'll skew results. (Results being looked at include number of pageviews and/or total time spent on site, as a non-paired Welch's *t* test.)

How do I work around or account for this problem?

Comment: It's a problem if there's some association between invalid assignments and the outcomes you are analyzing.  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: @whuber like I said, invalid assignments will be more prevalent among more-engaged people. And engagement relates to virtually all website-traffic outcomes.

Comment: @whuber , I realize now that this is probably more appropriately asked on [datascience.se]. If you agree, could you migrate it, please?

Comment: I think it's more likely to get good answers here on CV, especially if you would include some information about the analysis or analyses you plan to perform.

Comment: @whuber I've now included that.